# ActiveMQ different ways for receiving message

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Hi I have come across two ways for receiving message from a `ActiveMQ` broker:
(all classed mentioned below are in the `javax.jmx package`)

1) call `MessageConsumer.receive()` which which returns a Message

2) register a `MessageListener` for the MessageConsumer, and the listener has a `onMessage()`

Could I ask what really happens under the hood of these two ways?

Is this related to **pull/push**, **synchronous/asynchronous**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your guess is correct.

`messageConsumer.receive()` is **synchronous** by nature. It waits till is receive a message from the queue. So sometimes you don't want to wait infinitely so the method has timeout functionality:
    messageConsumer.receive(3000)

HERE  `3000` is the timeout in milliseconds. This way of communicating with broker is know as **request-reply** paradigm. It is in-fact **pull** for consumer.

And implementing `MessageListener` is **Asynchronous** by nature. It is **push** for consumer.